# Converting URL image link to picture from attribute data

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've got a page that a user clicks a symbol and a table is populated below with data. One of the attributes from the GeoJSON is an HTML link to an image. How can i convert that url to display the picture in the table?  Thanks

```
function mouseclick(e) {
document.getElementById("properties").innerHTML = "";  
var properties = e.target.feature.properties;
for (var prop in properties) {
   if (properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
        document.getElementById("properties").innerHTML = document.getElementById("properties").innerHTML + "<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>" + properties[prop] + "</td></tr>";
   } 
}
```

Comment: use it as the `src` attribute for an `img` tag

Comment: oh geez thanks haha that makes sense